# text break within tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the reason that the following code is producing an error with text break (\\)

```
\node (text_1) [draw=none, below=1cm of func, align=left, xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-1cm] 
{
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{9pt}{7.2}\selectfont
  {Some \\ code}
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: you need a text width key to specify a width before you can have multiple lines, but do you really want 9pt text on a 7.2pt baseline??? also you should not have the `\begingroup \endgroup` group or the `{}` group so that the implicit \par at the end of the node is in the scope of the size change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You need a `text width` key to allow multiple line text, also specifying a baseline spacing smaller than the font size seems very odd. Size changes should
always include a paragraph end so I removed the group, and finally there seemed to be a missing `;` for the tikz syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (text_1) [draw=none,  align=left, 
xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-1cm,text width=3cm,font=\small] 
{
  Some \\ code
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```